Proof Verification: There are only $4$ solutions to $a!+b!=c!$
I want to prove that there are only $4$ solutions to $a! + b! = c!$ using a proof by contradiction. I would like to confirm if this approach is valid. Here is my reasoning:
There are no solutions for $c = 0$ and $c = 1$. For $c = 2$, there are $4$ solutions: $(0, 0, 2)$, $(0, 1, 2)$, $(1, 0, 2)$, and $(1, 1, 2)$.
Now, assume that there are more than $4$ solutions, meaning there is at least one solution for $c > 2$.
Note that $c! = a! + b! > a!$, which implies $(c-1)! \geq a!$.
A similar argument gives $(c-1)! \geq b!$.
Thus, we have:
$$c!=c\cdot(c-1)!>2\cdot(c-1)!=(c-1)!+(c-1)!\geq a!+b!=c!$$
This leads to $c! > c!$, which is a contradiction.
Therefore, there are no more than $4$ solutions to that equation.

Compare your answer with the usual solutions, e.g. here.

Please check the tag description of [solution-verification]. For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be nonnegative integers such that $a!+b!=c!$. By symmetry, without loss of generality $a\leq b$. Then $a!=c!-b!$, and dividing by $a!$ yields
$$1=\frac{b!}{a!}-\frac{c!}{a!}=\frac{b!}{a!}-\frac{b!}{a!}\frac{c!}{b!}=\frac{b!}{a!}\left(\frac{c!}{b!}-1\right),$$
where all fractions are positive integers because $0\leq a\leq b\leq c$. It follows that $\frac{b!}{a!}=1$ and $\frac{c!}{b!}=2$, so $c=2$ and $a,b\in{0,1}$. All four combinations of course yield valid solutions.

Your Proof is correct , no worries there. There are various other ways to attempt it , which is highlighted via comment by user Dietrich Burde earlier itself.
Coming to your presentation , I think , there is a little something to improve.
We are showing the Contradiction for the claim that there are Solutions $c$ more than $2$.
We are not actually showing the Contradiction for the claim that there are more than $4$ Solutions.
There is a Difference between these two :

We might have not got all Solutions for $c=0$ , $c=1$ [[ We have to analyse that in Detail. Contradiction is not involved there ]]
There is nothing inherently special about $4$ here : It is just some coincidence. [[ Compare that with Quartic Equation which must have $4$ Solutions , where $5$ Solutions will give a Contradiction. Compare that with $4 \times 4$ Matrix having rank $5$ which is a Contradiction ]]


Please do not answer off-topic SV's (cf. comment on the quesiton).
